# Bicep Deployment error : An error occurred reading file. Could not find a part of the path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/bicep/storageaccount.bicep'

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy a bicep template using a powershell task in a devOps yml pipeline.

I have the following task:

```
  - task: AzurePowerShell@4
    displayName: "4.3) Deploy xxxxxx Synapse Infra"
    enabled: true
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureServiceConnection}}
      ScriptType: "InlineScript"
      azurePowerShellVersion: "LatestVersion"
      continueOnError: true
      errorActionPreference : "continue"
      Inline: |
        echo "Deploy Bicep template"
        $deployment = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
          -ResourceGroupName "rg-emdi-data-${{parameters.environment}}" `
          -TemplateFile "$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\bicep\storageaccount.bicep" `
          -envName "${{parameters.environment}}" `
          -location "${{parameters.location}}" `
          -storageId "$(storageID)" `
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error message :

```
ERROR: An error occurred reading file. Could not find a part of the path '/home/vsts/work/1/s/bicep/storageaccount.bicep'.
```

I can't understand why the file path is not resolved. My file structure is:
[image]

It works if I deploy main.bicep but fails when deploying the storage account module.
Any help would be great.

Comment: is it a deployment job or a normal job ?

Comment: hey @thomas, your question actually made me question whether the issue was not in the code but in the type of job.  I changed the deployment structure in the yml pipeline, to fit the .yml template deployment under a  normal job and it now works... not sure what difference this makes however but the file is now able to be located -  thank you!

Comment: if you're using a deployment job, you need to publish the files as artifacts if you need to use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deployment job does not automatically clone the source repo, so you can either use the artifact approach as mentioned by Thomas or you can add a `checkout: self` step.

From the documentation: [Deployment Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs)

> A deployment job doesn't automatically clone the source repo. You can
> checkout the source repo within your job with checkout: self.
> Deployment jobs only support one checkout step.

This would look like something like this inside the YAML pipeline:

```yaml
  - stage: Deployment
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployBicep
        environment: $(Environment)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                - task: AzurePowerShell@4
                  displayName: "4.3) Deploy xxxxxx Synapse Infra"
                  enabled: true
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.azureServiceConnection}}
                    ScriptType: "InlineScript"
                    azurePowerShellVersion: "LatestVersion"
                    continueOnError: true
                    errorActionPreference : "continue"
                    Inline: |
                      echo "Deploy Bicep template"
                      $deployment = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
                        -ResourceGroupName "rg-emdi-data-${{parameters.environment}}" `
                        -TemplateFile "$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\bicep\storageaccount.bicep" `
                        -envName "${{parameters.environment}}" `
                        -location "${{parameters.location}}" `
                        -storageId "$(storageID)" `
```